# Get last 20 minutes documents from MongoDB from Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have these two fields in every document in a collection.

```
"timeOne" : "06-28-2019T22:34:01",
"timeTwo" : ISODate("2019-06-28T22:34:01.870Z")
```

I would like to get documents that were created in the last 10 minutes in a Node.js function. Could someone help me this Node.js MongoDB query?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that maybe

```
col.find({ 
  "timeTwo" : { 
    $gte: moment().add(-20, 'minutes').toISOString()
  }   
})
```

Comment: the error says moment is not defined.

Comment: Of course, you have to install moment and require it. `npm install moment -S`. Or check the answer in duplicate :)